# Symfony2 "Error: Call to a member function toArray() on a non-object" when loading Roles from Database

Tags: symfony

I've been battling with this for several hours. I've built an app in Symfony 2.5 and when I go to log in as a user I receive this error:

> FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function toArray() on a
>   non-object in /var/www/cwwa/src/CWWA/CoreBundle/Entity/Users.php line
>   402

On line 402, I have this code:

```
/**
 * @inheritDoc
 */
public function getRoles()
{
    //return array('ROLE_CUSTOMER_USER');
    return $this->roles->toArray();
}
```

If I comment out `return $this->roles->toArray();` and replace it with the line above it, my user gets logged in to the system without an issue.

Now the main issue I see other people having has been with Symfony2 running on a server with PHP 5.4. My laptop was running this until I downgraded it to 5.3. This hasn't solved the issue.

Another method I used was to replace `return $this->roles->toArray();` to `return $this->roles;`, I get this error:

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 4 passed to
>   Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken::__construct()
>   must be an array, integer given, called in
>   /var/www/cwwa/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Provider/UserAuthenticationProvider.php
>   on line 96 and defined in
>   /var/www/cwwa/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Token/UsernamePasswordToken.php
>   line 36

I assume from this that the system is retrieving a value from the database.

My Database uses two tables for security. One User table and the other is the Role table. I've included the Entity files for both the User and Role tables below:

**Users.php**

```
<?php

namespace CWWA\CoreBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Users
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="CWWA\CoreBundle\Entity\Users")
 */
class Users implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;


    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="username", type="string", length=500, nullable=false)
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=500, nullable=false)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=500, nullable=false)
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="salt", type="string", length=500, nullable=false)
     */
    private $salt;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="first_name", type="string", length=125, nullable=false)
     */
    private $firstName;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="surname", type="string", length=45, nullable=false)
     */
    private $surname;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="customer", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $customer;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="created", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    private $created;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="is_active", type="boolean", nullable=false)
     */
    private $isActive;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="blocked", type="boolean", nullable=false)
     */
    private $blocked;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="access_list", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $accessList;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Roles", inversedBy="roles")
     *
     */
    private $roles;

    public function __construct()
    {
        return $this->isActive = true;
        return $this->salt = md5(uniqid(null, true));
        return $this->roles = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set username
     *
     * @param string $username
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setUsername($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get username
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }


    /**
     * Set email
     *
     * @param string $email
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get email
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * Set password
     *
     * @param string $password
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get password
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * Set salt
     *
     * @param string $salt
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setSalt($salt)
    {
        $this->salt = $salt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get salt
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getSalt()
    {
        return $this->salt;
    }

    /**
     * Set firstName
     *
     * @param string $firstName
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setFirstName($firstName)
    {
        $this->firstName = $firstName;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get firstName
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getFirstName()
    {
        return $this->firstName;
    }

    /**
     * Set surname
     *
     * @param string $surname
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setSurname($surname)
    {
        $this->surname = $surname;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get surname
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getSurname()
    {
        return $this->surname;
    }

    /**
     * Set customer
     *
     * @param integer $customer
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setCustomer($customer)
    {
        $this->customer = $customer;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get customer
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getCustomer()
    {
        return $this->customer;
    }

    /**
     * Set created
     *
     * @param \DateTime $created
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setCreated($created)
    {
        $this->created = $created;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get created
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getCreated()
    {
        return $this->created;
    }

    /**
     * Set isActive
     *
     * @param boolean $isActive
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setIsActive($isActive)
    {
        $this->isActive = $isActive;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get isActive
     *
     * @return boolean 
     */
    public function getIsActive()
    {
        return $this->isActive;
    }

    /**
     * Set blocked
     *
     * @param boolean $blocked
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setBlocked($blocked)
    {
        $this->blocked = $blocked;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get blocked
     *
     * @return boolean 
     */
    public function getBlocked()
    {
        return $this->blocked;
    }

    /**
     * Set accessList
     *
     * @param integer $accessList
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setAccessList($accessList)
    {
        $this->accessList = $accessList;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get accessList
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getAccessList()
    {
        return $this->accessList;
    }

    /**
     * Set roles
     *
     * @param integer $roles
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setRoles($roles)
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;

        return $this;
    }


    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getRoles()
    {
        //return array('ROLE_CUSTOMER_USER');
        return $this->roles;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
    }

    /**
     * @see \Serializable::serialize()
     */
    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize(array(
            $this->id,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @see \Serializable::unserialize()
     */
    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        list (
            $this->id,
        ) = unserialize($serialized);
    }

    public function isEqualTo(UserInterface $user)
    {
        return $this->id === $user->getId();
    }

}
```

**Roles.php**

```
<?php

namespace CWWA\CoreBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\RoleInterface;

/**
 * Roles
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="roles")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Roles implements RoleInterface
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="names", type="string", length=30, nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="role", type="string", length=20, nullable=false)
     */
    private $role;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Users", mappedBy="roles")
     */
    private $users;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->users = new ArrayCollection();
    }



    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set names
     *
     * @param string $names
     * @return Roles
     */
    public function setNames($names)
    {
        $this->names = $names;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get names
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getNames()
    {
        return $this->names;
    }

    /**
     * Set role
     *
     * @param string $role
     * @return Roles
     */
    public function setRole($role)
    {
        $this->role = $role;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get role
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getRole()
    {
        return $this->role;
    }

}
```

Any help would be fantastic, especially after 4 hours of hitting brick walls!

Answer (score 0):

In your `User` entity, the `roles` field should be inversed by `users` (the field on the other side of the entity).

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Roles", inversedBy="users")
 */
private $roles;
```

You might need to update your database.

Comment: I've made the changes to my User entity and I still receive the error. When you say I may need to update the database, how do you mean exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. The `toArray()` method isn't working because `$this->roles` is not an instance of `ArrayCollection`, instead it's an integer. I don't quite understand why you have three `return` statements in your `Users` constructor function; try getting rid of those first and just set the properties you need to set:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->isActive = true;
    $this->salt = md5(uniqid(null, true));
    $this->roles = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

Now the `toArray()` method should work as `$this->roles` should be an `ArrayCollection()`. Just remember that the Symfony security layer expects either an array of role objects or an array of strings.